# How to resolve django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1364, "Field 'name' doesn't have a default value")

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I'm getting this error from trying to create a superuser for my Django project. Unsure what table requires a default value for its `'name'` column.

After successfully creating migrations for my Django project I ran `python manage.py createsuperuser` to create the superuser and got the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1364, "Field 'name' doesn't have a default value")
```

I installed mysql (8.0) and I'm using *homebrew* on *OSX* and using *Python3* in a virtual environment.

I'm not sure which database the above command tries to engage, talk less of which table. In any case, I have gone through all tables in the db relevant to my project as well as in the `mysql` database and have run this command on the only name column found:

```
ALTER TABLE django_migrations ALTER COLUMN name SET DEFAULT '-'
```

But I am still getting this error. I have read up on `createsuperuser` in the Django docs as well as looked into some of the Django code but have gleaned very little value in solving this. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you use django auth user model?

Comment: Yes, the error was loosely connected to this but came from Django not properly connecting to MySQL

Comment: how you caonnect database. add DATABASE configuration code portion.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE django_content_type MODIFY COLUMN name character varying(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'not null';
```

Or if you want it to be empty:

```
ALTER TABLE django_content_type MODIFY COLUMN name character varying(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Taken from here: https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks/issues/139

Comment: Although this seems unrelated to OP's problem, I received this error message when running any migrations on a legacy project. This answer helped me on right tracks.

For some reason the project's database still had column `django_content_type.name`, even though it should have been removed by Django's migrations way back in version 1.8. `showmigrations` claimed that migration had been executed, so I ended up removing the column manually.

I'm not sure but this problem *might* have something to do with squashing migrations, since the error popped up after adding new migration after that.

Answer (score 0):

By default Django has a table called `auth_user` serving the user authentication which doesn't contain a field called `name`, so my assumption is that you have a custom `AUTH_USER_MODEL` defined in your `settings.py` which contains a field called `name` with not set default value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was a slightly misleading error coming from django connecting to mysql on the wrong port. I guess that Django was trying to engage the databases as though a connection had been established.